# Download Selenium Server

Tags: php, codeception

Can any one help me to guide, how can I download Selenium web driver? I have already installed codeception and already perform acceptance testing in php browser.

Comment: Maybe serverfault will be a better place to post this.

Comment: you using linux or windows ?

Comment: Iam using windows8 Sohail Yasmin

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

```
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar
```

you need to have java, and on the terminal you run

```
java -jar seleniumFile.jar
```